# Consume Server Sent in C#

Tags: javascript, c#

I am using ServiceStack.Client to consume, the data pushed by my server(which is an aspx page).

Below is the code which i use to consume the data using ServiceStack Client:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Threading;
using ServiceStack;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServerEventConnect connectMsg = null;
            var msgs = new List<ServerEventMessage>();
            var commands = new List<ServerEventMessage>();
            var errors = new List<Exception>();

            var client = new ServerEventsClient("https://testing.leadsquared.com/ReferralCampaign/Demo")
            {
                OnConnect =     e   =>  PrintMsg(e),
                OnCommand =     e   =>  PrintCmdMsg(e),
                OnMessage =     e   =>  PrintCmMsg(e),
                OnException =   e   =>  PrintExMsg(e)

            }.Start();



            Console.Read();
        }

        private static void PrintCmMsg(ServerEventMessage e)
        {
            if (e != null)
            {
                PrintMsg(e.Data);
            }
        }

        private static void PrintExMsg(Exception e)
        {
            if (e != null)
            {
                PrintMsg(e.Message);
            }
        }

        private static void PrintCmdMsg(ServerEventMessage e)
        {
            if (e != null)
            {
                PrintMsg(e.Data);
            }
        }

        private static void PrintMsg(ServerEventConnect e)
        {
            if (e!=null)
            {
                PrintMsg(e.Data); 
            }
        }

        private static void PrintMsg(string x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }


    }
}
```

When I run my code , the client does print any message on the console.
The ConnectionDisplayName property is "(not connected)".
If i subscribe to the same URL using javascript EventSource, i get the notifications.

My requirement is that I would want to consume the data by my server in C#.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the url needs to be the **BaseUri** where ServiceStack is hosted, i.e. the same url used in [JavaScript ServerEvents Client](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/JavaScript-Server-Events-Client), e.g:

```
var client = new ServerEventsClient(BaseUrl).Start();
```

It's not clear if `/ReferralCampaign/Demo` is the BaseUri or not.

You will also want to call `Connect()` to wait for the client to make a connection, e.g:

```
await client.Connect();
```

Then to see message events you'll need to call a ServiceStack Service that publishes a `Notify*` Event on `IServerEvents` API which you can use with a separate `JsonServiceClient` or the ServiceClient available in `ServerEventsClient`, e.g:

```
client.ServiceClient.Post(new PostRawToChannel {
    From = client.SubscriptionId,
    Message = "Test Message",
    Channel = channel ?? "*",
    Selector = "cmd.announce",
});
```

This is an example calling the [Chat PostRawToChannel](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/Chat/blob/master/src/Chat/Global.asax.cs#L168) ServiceStack Service:

```
public class ServerEventsServices : Service
{
    public IServerEvents ServerEvents { get; set; }

    public void Any(PostRawToChannel request)
    {
        // Ensure the subscription sending this notification is still active
        var sub = ServerEvents.GetSubscriptionInfo(request.From);
        if (sub == null)
            throw HttpError.NotFound("Subscription {0} does not exist".Fmt(request.From));

        // Check to see if this is a private message to a specific user
        if (request.ToUserId != null)
        {
            // Only notify that specific user
            ServerEvents.NotifyUserId(request.ToUserId, request.Selector, request.Message);
        }
        else
        {
            // Notify everyone in the channel for public messages
            ServerEvents.NotifyChannel(request.Channel, request.Selector, request.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

I also recommend looking at the C# [ServerEventTests](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/ServerEventTests.cs) for complete stand-alone examples using C# `ServerEventClient`.